# Give the matrix for the transformation T:

Tags: linear-algebra

> $a)$Give the matrix for the Transformation $T: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ that first reflects points through the $x$ - axis and then reflects through the line $y = x$
>
> $b)$How else can you describe this transformation?

Wouldn't this matrix be (I'm guessing) $\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}$

I'm not really sure

Comment: Where does $(1,0)$ map to under $T$?  What about $(0,1)$?  Graphing it might help.

Comment: Did you just guess that the identity matrix is the transformation you are finding?

Comment: As people have suggested, all you need to do is keep track of $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$. But describing any linear transformation with a matrix depends on your choice in basis. Selecting a different basis leads to a different matrix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to keep track of where $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ are mapped to.  In particular, we have
$$
(1,0) \mapsto (1,0) \mapsto (0,1)\\
(0,1) \mapsto (0,-1) \mapsto (-1,0)
$$
So, the matrix of $T$ is the matrix with these columns.  That is, 
$$
[T] = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$
It is worth noting that this is in fact the counterclockwise rotation by $90^\circ$.

---

We could also have expressed this composition of maps as a matrix multiplication.  That is,
$$
\pmatrix{0&1\\1&0} \pmatrix{1&0\\0&-1} = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}
$$